# Relation between $A^{*}B=B^{*}A$ and $AB^{*}=BA^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two matrices. Can we say $A^{*}B=B^{*}A$ implies $AB^{*}=BA^{*}$? how about when $A$ or $B$ are normal?

Any comments could be useful.

Thanks.

Comment: If $*$ means complex conjugate as opposed to conjugate transpose then yes this is always true as can be seen if you write each matrix as a sum of a real matrix and an imaginary matrix.

Comment: What do you mean by $A^{*}$ do you mean complex conjugate of $A$ or complex conjugate transpose of $A$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $A^*B = B^*A$.  That is, you know that $(A^*B)^* = (A^*B)$.  You want to show that $(BA^*)^* = BA^*$.

This is certainly not generally true when $A,B$ are not both normal.  As a counterexample, take
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0},  B = \pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}
$$
Notice that $AB^*$ is symmetric, but $B^*A$ is not.

The implication does hold if both $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.

Comment: What is your interpretation of $*$ here?

Comment: I've taken * to mean conjugate transpose

Comment: OK I now see this is more common according to wiki. In quantum field theory the dagger symbol is more commonly used, my mistake.

Comment: Whether that comment is correct in the context of this problem depends on what you mean by $^*$, which Graham and I have interpreted differently.

Comment: @Vahid: Please state, in a plain an understandable manner: what do you mean by *?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Complex conjugate transpose!

Comment: @Vahid then Graham's statement does not apply

Comment: @Vahid if you're still pressed for a reason your idea is wrong, try applying your approach to the example that I have provided in my answer.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom no I got it. Thats right. Thanks for your answer